# Android: ¿Como puedo hacer un aplicación para calcular fecha de nacimiento?

Tags: android, android-studio

Necesito realizar una aplicacion que me pida dos numeros por teclado que me sume, reste, multiplique y me muestre el resultado (una edad) 
y pueda saber el año de nacimiento de ese resultado es decir de esa edad. Serian minimo 4 botones(sume, reste, multiplique,limpiar) y que me lo muestre en pantalla tambien. Todo eso en un mismo layout una sola vista. 
Debe mostrar la fecha con el formato: Fecha de nacimiento de la edad(00) es (00/00/0000).

Ya tengo lo que vendría siendo la calculadora ( por decirlo de alguna forma ) solo que me falta hacer que con el resultado me diga la fecha de nacimiento. Gracias por leer y espero puedan ayudarme.

Comment: añade por favor el código que lleves avanzado, así como las dudas de ese mismo código, para que la comunidad sepa en que puntos en concreto ayudarte, lee [ask]

Comment: Nuevamente te invitamos a revisar [ask] para que formules tu pregunta, recuerda que de preferencia puedes agregar lo que hayas tratado o investigado, saludos.